# How can i create an IIS 6 WebSite remotely from Win2008R2 command line?

Tags: iis, command-line, vbscript, iis-6, windows-server-2008-r2

How can i do this if Iisweb.vbs is not available at IIS 6 Management Compatibility and AppCmd.exe only works with IIS7?